# Azure DevOps Pipeline Task to connect to Unix Server and execute commands

Tags: unix, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-task, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I am seeking to set up a Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps Services that will deploy
an application to a Unix server, where it then executes some unix commands as part
of the deployment.

Would appreciate some guidance on which pipeline Task(s) I can set up to therefore
achieve the following objectives:

1. Connect to the Unix server.
2. Execute the required Unix commands.

By the way, the Agents are currently installed on Windows hosts but we are looking to
extend that to Unix servers in due course, so a solution that fits both setups would
be ideal, even though the former is the priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, due to concerns raised about the install of private keys on the target server which is part of the SSH Deployment setup, we opted for the use of Deployment Groups which has enabled us to set up a persistent connection to our Linux server.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out task [SSH Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops).

> Use this task to run shell commands or a script on a remote machine using SSH. This task enables you to connect to a remote machine using SSH and run commands or a script.

If you need to copy files to the remote linux server. You can check out [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops).

You probably need to create a [SSH service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-ssh).  See steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) to create as service connection.

Comment: Hi @Levi Lu-MSFT we didn't go with that option (SSH Deployment task) in the end, due to concerns raised about the install of private keys on the target server. Instead, we opted for the use of Deployment Groups which has enabled us to set up a persistent connection to our Linux server.